# How to slow down the elements style transition onclick?

Tags: javascript, animation, onclick, transform

There is is a grid of four items which represents portfolio works, and when you click it, it changes elements position from 'relative' to 'fixed' and expands to fit to window width and height, but it should transform smoothly

I tried to add transition: all .5s, transition: position .5s; but none of them worked

```js
const projectItems = document.querySelectorAll('.project-item')
projectItems.forEach(item => {
  item.onclick = () => {
    item.classList.remove('relative')
    item.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh; z-index: 20'
  }
  item.ondblclick = () => {
    item.style.cssText = 'position: relative;'
  }

})
```

```html
<div class="relative" id="projects-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="projects-wrapper grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-2 gap-[1vw] mt-[5vw]">
      <div>
        <div class="project-item relative overflow-hidden">
          <div class="w-full h-[70%] overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
            <img src="./assets/img/hidden-image-1.jpg" class="h-full" alt="project item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="project-item relative overflow-hidden">
          <div class="w-full h-[70%] overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
            <img src="./assets/img/hidden-image-1.jpg" class="h-full" alt="project item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="project-item relative overflow-hidden">
          <div class="w-full h-[70%] overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
            <img src="./assets/img/hidden-image-1.jpg" class="h-full" alt="project item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="project-item relative overflow-hidden">
          <div class="w-full h-[70%] overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
            <img src="./assets/img/hidden-image-1.jpg" class="h-full" alt="project item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add and remove classes and set transition in the css.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Instead of changing the position property, use the transform property to scale and translate the element.
You can apply the transition property to the transform property to achieve a smooth effect.

Comment: this is good thanks for responding, but centering clicked item is kinda hard, because if I scroll below, and If item is still visible, and If I click it, does not moves to the center, I think it involves advanced Math here